# Check if callback error handler is defined correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling

I build a blog. The blog uses NodeJS with `mysql` module to talk with database. As this is a basic [CRUD](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh5pOZ68jOAhWlI8AKHYqnBt0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCreate%2C_read%2C_update_and_delete&usg=AFQjCNFE9JzuGHQ7kSdftyZ3MMe7nMBIqQ) application, I thought to break basic functionalities like *read*, *update*, *etc* into small modules and require them to a bigger one. The problem is that I haven't much experience with Node and it's asynchronous character, so I don't know if I implemented the callbacks from each module correctly. (I use the [Error First Callback Pattern](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)).

Take the bellow code as example. (The other modules are based on that structure as well)

```
module.exports = {
    delete_author: function(author_email, callback) {
        if (typeof(callback) === 'undefined') callback = function() {};

        if (author_email != null || author_email != undefined) {
            this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                if (err) callback(err);
                connection.query(
                    'DELETE FROM authors WHERE author_email = ?', [author_email],
                    function(err, result) {
                        connection.release();
                        if (err) {
                            callback(err);
                        } else {
                            callback(null, result);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        } else {
           callback(new Error('No parameter provided to delete_author call.'));
        }
    }
}
```

The above module is a part of a bigger MYSQL module (the one I reffer to it above).

So in `app.js` I type:

```
var mysql = require('MYSQL');

// start a connection

mysql.delete_author('author_email@some.com', function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // else do something here
}
```

Is my module structure okay? Am I defined and used the callback correctly? I want to point that this blog gets at least 20 visitors per day, and so far I haven't seen any strange behavior.

Comment: I would just add return statements where you invoke your callback function but that all looks fine from here. As long as your libraries follow that convention you should be fine. I'll also plug using promises for this sort of work.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 yes that about the return in callbacks I haven't understand. Do I have to use return in each callback's appear? And what about promises? How would you implement them here? Post an answer if you have time else explain it quickly.